# Number of vowels in the first 5 letters of a random arrangement

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, proof-explanation, intuition

I am struggling to understand the textbook solution of the following problem, my solution is correct, but I would like to understand the author's thinking

**Let $X$ be the number of vowels (not necessarily distinct) among the first five letters of a random arrangement of the expression "ELIZABETHTAYLOR"**

**Find the probability mass function of $X$**

*My Solution:*

For the case $X=5$, I imagined all the letters being in a bag, there are 6 vowels (Two A's, Two E's, one I and one O) and that I need to find the probability that the first 5 letters I pick are vowels, this translates to:

${5\choose 5}\times \frac{6}{15}\times\frac{5}{14}\times\frac{4}{13}\times\frac{3}{12}\times\frac{2}{11} = \frac{720}{360,360} = \frac{2}{1001}$

For the case $X=4$,

${5\choose 4}\times \frac{6}{15}\times\frac{5}{14}\times\frac{4}{13}\times\frac{3}{12}\times\frac{9}{11} = \frac{720}{360,360} = \frac{45}{1001}$

etc.

The author gives this general solution:

$$\frac{{5\choose i}\times {_6}P{_i} \times {_9}P{_{5-i}} \times 10!}{15!}  $$ which I don't understand the intuition of. I see the first combinatorial is the same as mine, but I don't understand why we are multiplying two permutations which represent the vowels and consonants by $10!$. Can someone please give me the explanation and guide me through the authors method? Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: $10! / 15! = \frac{1}{11}\frac{1}{12}\frac{1}{13}\frac{1}{14}\frac{1}{15}$. That appears in your formula as well , so it seems there is some amount of similarity in the approach. Also, "Elizabeth Taylor", interesting.

Comment: my goodness I can't believe I missed that, thank you! @SarveshRavichandranIyer, should one come up with the general formula directly or derive it from seeing the case-by-case patterns? Because I cannot see myself coming up with the general formula the author gave just from definition

Comment: But I don't understand the apparent use of "ordinary" permutations.  At some point the multi-set nature of the Vowels and Consonants needs to appear.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @lulu may you please elaborate?

Comment: It seems that we count permutations, not the result of the action of permutations on the given word... @lulu

Comment: To me, $_6P_i$ means the number of ways to choose $i$  elements out of $6$ distinct options.  But that's not the situation here.  Here you need to choose $i$ objects from the multiset $\{A,A, E, E, I ,O\}$.

Comment: @dan_fulea  If you mean that we are imagining that we had the set $\{A_1,A_2, E_1, E_2, I, O\}$ then I agree with you.  And perhaps that's the answer.  I was taking the pair $A_1A_2$, say, to be the same as the pair $A_2A_1$ but perhaps that was not the intent.  But, yes.  Read your way, the formula is correct.

Comment: OK, than we have to ask the question: The given word is $$ELIZ\color{red}{A}BETHT\color{blue}{A}YLOR\ ,$$and we can permute using different permutations to get the same word $\color{red}{A}\color{blue}{A}ELIZ\ BETHT\ YLOR=\color{blue}{A}\color{red}{A}ELIZ\ BETHT\ YLOR$, when written black on white paper. What do we count here? Permutations or the words resulted after applying them (when modelling the probability space)?

Comment: It's an interesting ambiguity.  I read the problem as asking "amongst all distinct $5$ letter words drawn from the given letters, what's the distribution of the number of vowels?".  That is not the same as asking for "of all the draws of $5$ letters from the available ones, with multiplicity, what is the distribution of the number of vowels. "  The official answer suggests that the second reading is intended.

Comment: Side note:  Not sure about the status of $Y$ here.  It's a "vowel glide", if memory serves, or perhaps a "semivowel" (not sure I ever understood the difference).  And, personally, I'd just go ahead and call those things vowels.  Not sure what the consensus is, if there is one.

Comment: Oh, it's not confusing, [see this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37688/what-is-the-difference-between-a-glide-and-a-semivowel).  (though I see from the comments on that link that not everyone agrees with this distinction).  A glide precedes the vowel, a semivowel follows it.  So , here, the $Y$ is a semivowel.   I do understand that this is not the important issue here.

Comment: in my book $Y$ is a vowel, but the exercise chooses to not to consider it one @lulu

Comment: @lulu THANK you for all your input, I really appreciate it. I will let these thoughts decant in my head

Comment: @Kam I'm going one step further and trying to write an answer. For your detail, I believe you merit this. +1.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer That is very kind of you, many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'll go for this, given I had a helpful comment first up. I'll call Elizabeth Taylor as Liz Taylor or Liz below, I hope she does not mind.

---

Our idea is to think about the individual components in the formula $$
\frac{\binom{5}{i} \times \  _6P_i\ \times\  _9P_{5-i} \times 10!}{15!}
$$

For the purposes of this answer, it seems the following happens.

- All the letters of $ELIZABETHTAYLOR$ are treated as different from each other, something like $$E_1L_1IZA_1BE_2T_1HT_2A_2YL_2OR$$
  (I can hear Liz Taylor screaming in the distance).
- Some kind of choices and permutations are made.
- Are the letters combined back later? Thus began, the suspense novel "Was Liz Taylor put back together?".

---

Tackle the $15!$ first. Clearly, $15!$ is the number of ways in which one can permute $15$ different letters. So we must differentiate the letters of Liz Taylor's name to begin with, and then we realize that the sample space is probably the space of all permutations of the differentiated letters. So an example of a permutation is $$
IZL_2A_1BE_1OE_2T_1HRA_2L_1YT_2
$$

Let's now go into the components. Make the following preliminary observation that there are $6$ vowels and $9$ consonants in this permutation, all distinct from each other now.

We use a table to illustrate the process of permutation creation. On the right, is a particular term of the numerator. In the middle is the reason it's there. For $i=3$ we will build a permutation using the author's schema, and place the example we build on the right.

| Term | Reason | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\binom{5}{i}$ | We choose $i$ positions out of the first $5$ | Positions numbered $1,2,4$ were chosen |
| $_6P_i$ | We arrange $i$ vowels out of the $6$ in a certain order | Take say $E_2 O E_1$ |
| $_9P_{5-i}$ | We arrange $5-i$ consonants out of the $9$ available in a certain order. | Say $YT_1$ |
| $10!$ | There are $10$ leftover letters. We arrange them in any order. | $ZA_2RL_2L_1T_2BHA_1I$ |

Now, let us see what permutation is constructed out of this.

- Positions $1,2,4$ will be occupied by the vowels $E_2OE_1$ *in that order*.
- Positions $3,5$ (the leftover positions) will be the consonants $YT_1$ *in that order*.
- Positions $6$ to $15$ will the letters $ZA_2RL_2L_1T_2BHA_1I$ *in that order*.

At the end, we get $$
E_2OYE_1T_1ZA_2RL_2L_1T_2BHA_1I
$$

That is how the author intends to build permutations, and that's how his schema is made.

But I can hear Liz Taylor saying : "This isn't a permutation of $ELIZABETHTAYLOR$! This is a permutation of $E_1L_1IZA_1BE_2T_1HT_2A_2YL_2OR$, which isn't the same name(duh)!!"

How can we assuage her concerns?

---

To help out Liz, we must understand why the author chose to count the way he did.

What if the author ignored the denominator and start out with the letters $ELIZABETHTAYLOR$ instead of $E_1L_1IZA_1BE_2T_1HT_2A_2YL_2OR$? Then I claim that the author's scheme *could have made them overcount*.

The reason for that is rather obvious. For example, the permutations $EE$  and $EE$ are the same (really?), while the permutation $E_1E_2$ is different from the permutation $E_2E_1$ when the two letters are identified distinctly.

Imagine the author was doing the second step, where he had to choose $3$ vowels out of $6$ , say. The number of permutations is *not* equal to $_6P_3$, because the six vowels are *not* distinct in $ELIZABETHTAYLOR$. So that's where the overcounting would have occurred had he proceeded with this step.

> *The author's idea to differentiate the letters, was done to avoid overcounting with his proposed scheme*. He came up with the scheme first, then realized that he had to differentiate the letters to avoid trouble.

But we still haven't answered Liz's question (and she's getting impatient) : how do we retrieve a permutation of
$ELIZABETHTAYLOR$ from the permutation written there?

---

For this, we recall a useful notion in probability : a function between sample spaces, often called a probabilistic mapping. This is a function $f : \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ between sample spaces, which allows us to think of events in one space in terms of events in another space.

Let $\Omega_1$ be the set of all permutations of $E_1L_1IZA_1BE_2T_1HT_2A_2YL_2OR$ and $\Omega_2$ the set of all permutations of $ELIZABETHTAYLOR$. Then, the map $f$ from $\Omega_1$ to $\Omega_2$ is defined as the identification of all the "distinct" letters in the corresponding permutation in $\Omega_1$, interpreted then as a permutation in $\Omega_2$. To give an example,$$
f(E_2OYE_1T_1ZA_2RL_2L_1T_2BHA_1I) = EOYETZARLLTBHAI
$$

What's something nice about this map? It's the following : every element of $\Omega_2$ has *exactly* $2^4$ *preimages*.

To prove this, look at a particular permutation, say $$
EOYETZARLLTBHAI
$$

How could a permutation from $\Omega_1$ have been mapped to this? The only way is that some letters were identified together. Now, there are $2$ copies each of $E,T,A,L$ in the permutation above. Simply numbering the $T$s with $1,2$, the $E$s with $1,2$ and so on can be done in $2^4$ different ways and leads to $2^4$ different elements of $\Omega_2$. For example, $$
f(E_2OYE_1T_1ZA_2RL_2L_1T_2BHA_1I) = EOYETZARLLTBHAI \\
f(E_1OYE_2T_1ZA_1RL_1L_2T_2BHA_2I) = EOYETZARLLTBHAI 
$$

and you can perhaps see how the other of $16$ possible preimages can be written : by permuting the $1$s and $2$s among $E,T,A,L$ subscripts till exhaustion.

Remember that $f$ can be used to map subsets of $\Omega_1$ to $\Omega_2$ and vice-versa via the image and preimage operations. That is, if $S_1 \subset \Omega_1$, then $f(S_1) = \{f(\sigma) : \sigma \in S_1\}$  is a subset of $\Omega_2$.

Similarly, if $S_2 \subset \Omega_2$, then $f^{-1}(S_2) = \{x \in \Omega_1 : f(x) \in S_2\}$ is a subset of $\Omega_1$. From what we discussed earlier, we have the relation $$
|f^{-1}(S_2)| = 16|S_2| \quad ; \quad |f(S_1)| = \frac{|S_1|}{16}
$$
where $S_1,S_2$ are as above.

The big observation occurs when we think about the sizes of $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$. What is $|\Omega_1|$? It is $15!$. What is $|\Omega_2|$? Indeed, that is $\frac{15!}{16}$, because we can use $S_2 = \Omega_2$ in our discussion above to get this conclusion. Now, we can easily see that $f$ is indeed very special.

> $f$ is a *probability preserving map* between $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$. In other words, for every set $A_1 \subset \Omega_1$, we have $\mathbb P_1(A_1) = \mathbb P_2(f(A_1))$. Similarly, for every event $A_2 \subset \Omega_2$, we have $\mathbb P_2(A_2) = \mathbb P_1(f^{-1}(A_2))$ (note : $\mathbb P_1,\mathbb P_2$ indicate that we are taking the probabilities of events in $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ respectively).

The proof is very easy. One direction of it would be
$$
\mathbb P_1(A_1) = \frac{|A_1|}{|\Omega_1|} = \frac{\frac{|A_1|}{16}}{\frac{|\Omega_1|}{16}} =\frac{|f(A_1)|}{|f(\Omega_1)|} = \frac{|f(A_1)|}{|\Omega_2|} = \mathbb P_2(f(A_1))
$$

I'd imagine you can go the other way as well.

Now, having this probability preserving map in our armory, let's proceed to place Liz's and our reader's mind at rest.

---

Recall the random variable $X$, the number of vowels among the first letters in a random permutation of $ELIZABETHTAYLOR$. Note that $\{X=i\}$ for $i=0,1,2,3,4,5$ is an event of $\Omega_2$.

For $i=0,1,2,3,4,5$,

- Consider the event in $\Omega_1$ given by $$
  E_i = \{X=i\} =  \{\sigma \in \Omega_1 : \text{ There are $i$ vowels in the first $5$ letters in $\sigma$}\}
  $$
  and the event in $\Omega_2$ given by $$
  F_i = \{\sigma' \in \Omega_2 : \text{There are $i$ vowels in the first lettes in $\sigma'$}\}
  $$
- One sees that $f(F_i) = E_i$ for all $i$. Why? Indeed, vowels continue to be vowels and consonants continue to be consonants under the map $f$ : it only changes the identification among the letters, but doesn't change whether each is a letter or a consonant. Therefore, this is true.
- The author's schema shows that $\mathbb P_1(F_i) = \frac{\binom{5}{i} \times \  _6P_i\ \times\  _9P_{5-i} \times 10!}{15!}$. We already discussed how the author uses each of the terms to come up with a permutation in $\Omega_1$, and how it avoids overcounting.
- *Because $f$ is probability-preserving*, it is also true that $$
  \boxed{
  \mathbb P_2(\{X= i\}) = \mathbb P_2(E_i) = \mathbb P_2(f(F_i)) = \mathbb P_1(F_i) = \frac{\binom{5}{i} \times \  _6P_i\ \times\  _9P_{5-i} \times 10!}{15!}
  }
  $$

---

So that completes the loop. To perhaps put it from the author's perspective.

- He cam up with a scheme for generating permutations with the desired number of vowels.
- Then, he realized that he was *overcounting* if he performed his scheme with permutations of $ELIZABETHTAYLOR$. So he *simply had* to differentiate the letters of the name.
- However, he rescued the situation by realizing that there is a very *natural* and *probability preserving map* between the two sample spaces given by the permutation with the identified and non-identified letters.
- This allowed him to reconnect the permutation of the marked letters, with a permutation in the set $\{X=i\}$, while not needing to change the probability. Thus, his task was achieved.

Now, let's be honest. I did my best to explain the naturality of $f$ as a map, but I really think the author's scheme is excessively confusing. I prefer the OP's approach.

However, Liz is happy, since we returned to $\Omega_2$ in the end. I hope others are , as well.

Side note : probability-preserving maps are a big deal in measure theory and dynamical systems. Glad to have given you and Liz a first-hand look at their usefulness.

Comment: I want to vote this as the best answer ever given on MSE, Sarvesh, you have absolutely floored me, I will be sharing this answer with as many friends as I can, thank you from the bottom of my heart, i came looking or wood and I found a diamond, may you have an excellent rest of your year, bless your soul!

Comment: I might have questions, but for now I am just savoring this answer as much as I can

Comment: @Kam I thank you for providing me with enough information to write this answer and be of service to you. I hope that , in particular, I could communicate the usefulness of measure-preserving transformations. Note that these are often referred to as *ergodic* transformations in literature, and ergodic transformations form a whole different subject because of intricate links to dynamical systems. As you saw with the toy example linking permutations of different names of Liz, the same can be done with very complicated sample spaces, providing for a rich theory.

Comment: Oh, pardon me : $f$ is a "probability mapping" that , because it preserves the probability of events, is called a "measure preserving transformation". Yes, it's nice to see how simple questions can knock on the door of interesting recent research.

Comment: I will remember these two days for as long as I live, thanks again Sarvesh, I have much to learn from this information you provided, and I have no doubt it will prove very useful in my pursuit of probability and statistics

Comment: @Kam Thank you so much, I am very glad I was able to be of great service to you today.